# How to export python program as zip so that it runs on other computers?

Tags: python, zip

My goal is to create a .zip file which includes my python code and a batch file that runs that python code without installing anything else in the user's system but only uses files within the .zip. This means the batch file can't run `python main.py` since that would first involve getting the user to install python, which in my purposes, is just inconvenient and bad.

My first instinct was to put my code in a folder. Then, create a virtualenv with all dependencies installed. Create a batch file with the following code:

```
".venv/Scripts/python.exe" code_path/main.py
```

Package the code, virtualenv, and batch file in a zip file then pass that around to the users.

The problem I have with this is that I feel that it's dumb to add the virtualenv to the zip file. EDIT: Even if I were to add it, the .venv wouldn't even work for other systems apparently.

I tried other solutions like making a `.exe` instead with pyinstaller, but it keeps popping up with false positive detections from some security vendors like Chrome and Windows Defender, so I strayed away from this path and tried using `.zip` files instead.

EDIT: question currently limited to solutions for Windows 10/11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running python script without python installed on pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388912/running-python-script-without-python-installed-on-pc)

Comment: What you are describing is not possible *if* the user does not have python installed.   Consider that "you pass around the zip file", you have exe file there. How about people who would not be running on Mac or Linux ?  Anyway, you could try https://nuitka.net/

Comment: what i meant by "installing python" is by using the official python installer to install python in the user's system. i can include the python program in the zip somehow, though i have no clue on how to do that. i haven't specified the OS and architecture in the question though, so i'll edit the question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a nice solution for the problem you face.
You could build the environment and apps in a container, which is based on official python docker image, then pack and distribute your python-app image.

The following Dockerfile is an example:
Prepare your app .py in `/usr/src/app` and write the requrements in `requrements`

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]
```

Visit https://hub.docker.com/_/python for more detail.

Comment: how would i use a batch file (or similar) to open the program? looks like i'd have to make the user install docker to get the app out of the container, though i have zero experience with docker and have no idea to know if this could be a viable solution

Comment: @TNTzx you would have to install Docker on that user's system, so this answer does not answer your question at all. Use py2exe and use code signing to overcome the security issues, which are there for a reason. It would be a giant security risk to just run code without the user installing anything else.

Comment: again, i tried packaging the app with exe freezer programs but it comes up with false positive virus detections from various security vendors, so this isn't an option for me

Comment: @TNTzx sounds like you did not sign it properly

Comment: i thought signing exes costed money, which i don't really have much of. it's just a hobby project, i'd rather stick with the false positive detections than spend money